# ldconfig returning non-zero code: 1

Tags: shell, docker

I'm trying to build a docker image containing the oracledb client and nodejs, but I'm getting the error `The command '/bin/sh -c ldconfig' returned a non-zero code: 1` on `RUN ldconfig`.

I cannot find anything to help me solve this problem and I've been trying to solve this myself for the last 2hours, and I need help!

Additional info:
Oddly, when I go into the container with `docker exec -it container_name sh` and then execute `ldconfig`, it runs fine...

This is the `dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:9.11-alpine
WORKDIR /
COPY ./oracle /opt/oracle
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache libaio && \
    mkdir /etc/ld.so.conf.d && \
    sh -c "echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf" && \
    ldconfig
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ENV PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2:$PATH
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Comment: Do you get to see the actual error produced by the command somewhere? It's likely a permission problem.

Comment: No I can't find a way to see the error messages.. I doubt it's the permission problem since it runs the instructions with `root` user.

Comment: Judging from the docker file that you posted, it never says to run `sh -c ldconfig` anywhere.

Comment: According to the error message, I have to assume that docker take the ldconfig at line 8 and executes it as `sh -c ldconfig`

Comment: Which it shouldn't be doing as it is chained with the previous line through `&&`.  Also, if it had done that with the previous line (`sh -c '...'`), you'd have some strange behaviour.

Comment: How do you know the error is from the ldconfig and not, say, the mkdir in the && chain?  How are you solving the glibc issue with Alpine Linux?    FWIW there is an Oracle Linux with Instant Client at https://store.docker.com/images/oracle-instant-client

Comment: @Kusalananda I see... Hmm.. I have no idea. I decided to use a docker image that has preinstalled oracle client with nodejs since I couldn't get it working.

Comment: @ChristopherJones I tried separating the RUN commands into separate ones and found that it builds successfully if I exclude the `ldconfig` command. The error message `The command '/bin/sh -c ldconfig' returned a non-zero code: 1` appears once I add the `ldconfig` command.

Comment: What about the second question I asked (glibc)?

Comment: @ChristopherJones I haven't tried solving anything regarding glibc. I decided not to spend more time on it since I had to get some work done.

Comment: @ChristopherJones I've just looked up on their issues on github regarding running oracledb on alpine, and apparently it's incompatible with the musl glibc alpine uses. So I will resort to using node-slim version instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See my blog post series [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1) that shows using Instant Client in Oracle Linux containers.

Also see the node-oracledb installation manual section [Using node-oracledb in Docker](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#docker).

The latest sample [Oracle Instant Client container Dockerfile](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleInstantClient/dockerfiles/19/Dockerfile) automatically pulls the required RPMs - no manual download required.  Oracle Instant Client 19 will connect to Oracle DB 11.2 or later.

Comment: Sweet, I'll go through that soon. I did get my node (slim version) and oracle instant client to work, but ended up with a 700MB image. I hope maybe you'd have a better solution.

Comment: This does not answer the OP question.

Comment: It solves the OP's problem, which is how to use node-oracledb in a container.  The brief answer is "don't use alpine, use something that works and is supported"

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 9):

In alpine `ldconfig` requires the configuration directory as an argument.

Try running `ldconfig` like this:

```
ldconfig /etc/ld.so.conf.d
```

Theoretically that should work.

Comment: Bad Alpine.  Again.

Comment: This doesn't work on Alpine too. Easier to add required libs to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or make symbolic links in `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/lib` or `/lib`

Comment: @vitalh : I'm guessing something changed since 2019 ...